# How to do grayscale -> RGB pixel replication with x86 intrinsics

Tags: c++, image-processing, sse, intrinsics

So assume I have the following code sample, below:

```
   /* replicate the single-channel gray value into 3 RGB pixel values (R=G=B) */
    auto outPtr = convertedImageBuffer->data();
    auto inPtr = *m_img;

    for (auto p : inPtr)
    {
        outPtr[0] = p;
        outPtr[1] = p;
        outPtr[2] = p;

        outPtr += 3;
    }
```

m_img is a `shared_ptr` containing `std::vector<uint8_t>`; "outPtr" is a raw byte-pointer that also originates from another managed byte-buffer.  "inPtr" points to a linear buffer that's an 8-bit grayscale image.

The for-loop makes sure the linear byte-buffer in outPtr has input pixels from inPtr[] duplicated 3 times.  Of course, this way seems very inefficient to me.

How would I do this with x86 intrinsics?

Comment: I doubt that any intrinsic can help. Triplicating is so short... You can try to multiply by 0x01010101 and write as an int, overlapping the previous. One write instead of three, but probably with a misalignment penalty.

Comment: What does your compiler with full optimisation produce? I'd bet it'd be better than you could do without a lot of effort.

Comment: SSSE3 `pshufb` (`_mm_shuffle_epi8`) seems like the way to go.  Do 8 byte loads, using the low 5 of them.  Do 16 byte stores, incrementing your output pointer by 15 (so overlap by 1).  Stop early if you need to avoid reading and/or writing past the ends of arrays.  (Or 16-byte loads with 3 different shuffle-control vectors could be good.)

Comment: You should measure first to make sure this is actually an interesting perf bottleneck.  Beware of using SIMD, because it can cause pipeline stalls -- there are tradeoffs to using it, especially for small snippets of code.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53: What pipeline stalls are you talking about on modern x86 that are specific to using SIMD instructions?  Perhaps you're thinking of in-order ARM CPUs where the SIMD unit is often more loosely coupled with the integer pipeline, and moving data between pipelines can stall?  On real x86 microarchitectures, it very much *is* worth using SIMD instructions even if it's just a 16-byte load + store to copy a struct, or do 2x or 4x integer adds not in a loop.  Compilers do aggressively use SSE on x86 for that reason, and so does libc strlen, memcpy, etc.

Comment: (Loading constants from .rodata that you wouldn't need for scalar can of course miss in cache, but frequent small calls to this will keep the data hot, and infrequent but long-running loops will amortize the miss cost.  Only if this function is seriously "colde" (infrequently called for small sizes) would you not want to load shuffle constants for SIMD.)

Comment: Please do not tag c++ with c.

Answer (score 4):

The `pshufb` instruction fits the task perfectly. Reading 16 bytes at a time and using three lookup tables from the table of 48 bytes, one can then output 48 bytes in one iteration. Why 48 bytes? The loads and stores can be possibly aligned and not a single lane / computational resource in the SIMD registers is wasted.

```c
 // initialise once outside a loop
 alignas(16) const uint8_t lut[48]= { 0,0,0, 1,1,1, 2,2,2, ..., 15,15,15 };
 auto const lut0 = _mm_load_si128(lut);
 auto const lut1 = _mm_load_si128(lut + 16);
 auto const lut2 = _mm_load_si128(lut + 32);
     
 // then loop over the data
 auto data = _mm_load_si128(input_ptr);
 auto out0 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(data, lut0);
 auto out1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(data, lut1);
 auto out2 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(data, lut2);
 _mm_store_si128(output_ptr, out0);
 _mm_store_si128(output_ptr + 16, out1);
 _mm_store_si128(output_ptr + 32, out2);
```

Use `_mm_loadu_si128` / `_mm_storeu_si128` if your input / output data might not be 16-byte aligned.

Comment: `_mm_setr_epi8`  would be the normal way to init the LUT vectors.  Making the array `const` (like my edit) or even `static const` should help avoid silly compilers actually constructing it on the stack to load from, though.  But `_mm_setr_epi8` will let the compiler figure out where to get the data, merging duplicates if you have the same vector elsewhere.  (Like how compilers handle string literals.)

Comment: A perf comparison would be interesting.  I have done enough perf micro-opts to know that things that seemingly should be faster, sometimes are not.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53: I'd expect this to bottleneck on shuffle+store throughput of 1/clock each on modern Skylake / Zen CPUs, so 16 result bytes / cycle.  (I've done enough CPU-architecture perf tuning / analysis for modern x86 to usually predict pretty accurately.) Maybe at worst half that, or hitting a memory bottleneck.  But I'd expect scalar code probably wouldn't auto-vectorize, certainly not this nicely, and would probably run at about 1 byte per clock; about 16x slower.  Even if the vectorized version doesn't run perfectly, 10x faster is a *very* reasonable expectation.

Answer (score 0):

SSSE3 `pshufb` (`_mm_shuffle_epi8`) seems like the way to go.  Do 8 byte loads, using the low 5 of them.  Do 16 byte stores, incrementing your output pointer by 15 (so overlap by 1).

Stop early to avoid reading and/or writing past the ends of arrays, doing the last element scalar.  (You can do one final vector that goes right up to the last-but-1 element, assuming your problem size is always big enough for more than 1 full vector.)

Or 16-byte loads with 3 different shuffle-control vectors would be even better; as Aki's answer shows that allows full use of all the data in each load and store, with no overlap. (48 bytes = LCM(3, 16)).

---

If you can't assume SSSE3, it's a lot more inconvenient and perhaps not worth doing with SIMD.  Scalar `x * 0x01010101` will broadcast a byte to 4 bytes, and doing overlapping 4-byte stores will be more efficient than 3 separate byte stores.  (Use `memset(dst, tmp, 4)` or something for an unaligned may-alias store, unless you want to use GNU C `typedef uint32_t aliasing_u32 __attribute__((aligned(1),may_alias))`.